# ArrayList inside for-loop for ngx image gallery

Tags: angular, arraylist, iterator, image-gallery, ngx-bootstrap

this.imageDataPoints is my dynamic ArrayList, and I want to set the media_url property to  this.galleryImages = [
          {
            small: '',
            medium: '',
            big: '',
          }
        ];

please help me to bind this using loop or any other solution.

```
this.imageDataPoints = [
   {
      "user_id":11,
      "media_type":"IMAGE",
      "media_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dev_platform_media_ingest/o/155%2Ftemp_photo.png?generation=1512207708761660&alt=media",
      "media_name":"155/temp_photo.png"
   },
   {
      "user_id":43,
      "media_type":"IMAGE",
      "media_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dev_platform_ingest_media/o/155%2FKendall%20Jenner.jfif?generation=1511847043169272&alt=media",
      "media_name":"155/Kendall Jenner.jfif"
   },
   {
      "user_id":11,
      "media_type":"IMAGE",
      "media_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dev_platform_media_ingest/o/155%2Fmaxres.jpg?generation=1512207530832065&alt=media",
      "media_name":"155/maxres.jpg"
   },
   {
      "user_id":43,
      "media_type":"IMAGE",
      "media_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dev_platform_ingest_media/o/155%2Fmaxres.jpg?generation=1511869575663768&alt=media",
      "media_name":"155/maxres.jpg"
   },
   {
      "user_id":11,
      "media_type":"IMAGE",
      "media_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dev_platform_media_ingest/o/155%2FFacebook%20Cover%20-%20Untitled.jpg?generation=1512490205942447&alt=media",
      "media_name":"155/Facebook Cover - Untitled.jpg"
   },
   {
      "user_id":43,
      "media_type":"IMAGE",
      "media_uri":"https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/dev_platform_ingest_media/o/155%2FKendall%20Jenner.jpg?generation=1511869598503407&alt=media",
      "media_name":"155/Kendall Jenner.jpg"
   }
]
```

Comment: This is no correct Javascript-Object: 
    this.galleryImages = [ { small: '', medium: '', big: '', } ];

Comment: For me its not clear what your question is ? How is your array dynamic ? is it an observable ? is it dynamically changing through user input ?
Does every array[i].media_uri have to be = [ { small: '', medium: '', big: '', } ];
please be more precise what you want

Comment: I want like this:

Comment: this.galleryImages = [
      {
        small: 'https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/assets/img/1-small.jpeg',
        medium: 'https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/assets/img/1-medium.jpeg',
        big: 'https://lukasz-galka.github.io/ngx-gallery-demo/assets/img/1-big.jpeg'
      }
    ];

Comment: please take a look: https://codepen.io/lukasz-galka/project/editor/XGgxrL

Comment: or https://plnkr.co/edit/D1tdBCeFo6L9tMOCOb9p?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understand your Question a simple forEach ([MDN-Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)) would be enough.

```js
  this.imageDataPoints.forEach((picture, index) => {
     picture.media_uri = this.galleryImages[index];
  });
```

Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/AiTTBuWliNaev3AXksYJ?p=preview

Please correct me, if i understood the Question wrong and give more Detail about it.

Comment: Yes! but I got error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined

Comment: Actually, you did it opposite.

Comment: I want something like this:

Comment: this.galleryImages = [
      {
        small: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/155%2Ftemp_photo.png',
        medium: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/155%2Ftemp_photo.png',
        big: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/155%2Ftemp_photo.png'
      },
      {
        small: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/155%2FKendall%20Jenner.jfif?',
        medium: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/155%2FKendall%20Jenner.jfif?',
        big: 'https://www.googleapis.com/download/storage/155%2FKendall%20Jenner.jfif?'
      }
   ];

Comment: I am doing this but only one image will displaying (overwrite it):

Comment: for (let i: number = 0; i < this.imageDataPoints.length; i++) {
    this.galleryImages = [
      {
        small: this.imageDataPoints[i].media_uri,
        medium: this.imageDataPoints[i].media_uri,
        big: this.imageDataPoints[i].media_uri,
      }
    ];
  }